# set the width of the button to the LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-checkbox

I am trying to set the width of the button in the `lila` LinearLayout but I am getting it just like in the screenshot. How can I set the width for the button? I am facing another Problem the item number beside the checkboxes are a Little bit higher than the Level of the Checkbox. How can I configure that programmatically to set them to the same level ?

```
private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(items.get(i) + "\n");
        cb.setId(i + 10);
        ll.addView(cb);

    }



    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("submit");
            // With this line below I am not getting the button displayed.
    //btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 40));
    ll.addView(btn);

}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think as you are setting with as 10px , your text is clipped out because of Button default style padding. try setting width as 200 px and height 40px. The line you write is not wrong, it is supposed to work with correct params.

Comment: and try setting gravity if linear layout "left | center vertically"

Comment: @MAbdulSami: I set it to `.LayoutParams(500, 150)` and it Looks better.  Do you know why the numbers are not at the same Level as the checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About number displayed higher than checkbox.
In your code `cb.setText(items.get(i) + "\n");` you are putting new line, so next to checkbox is diplayed number AND new line

Comment: But when I deleted it I got `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2` How should it be?

Comment: try coverting int to string or add "".